# Adding a link to an invoice into a notification message

Tags: html, moqui

I have a screen with a form contaning invoices I want to notify the user with. The screen is used as `bodyScreenLocation` for the `EmailTemplate`. Up to here, it works. I wanted to add a link for each invoice so that the user can open the document right from withing the message. How to construct the path? This way it does not work:

[image]

This field is created in a form, that is included in a screen. This screen is used in a template called using 
`<service-call name="org.moqui.impl.EmailServices.send#EmailTemplate" async="true">`

---

Added 18.10.2016

I attempted to use your advice.

```
<actions>
    <entity-find entity-name="mantle.account.invoice.Invoice" list="invoiceList"/>

    <script>
        import org.moqui.impl.context.WebFacadeImpl

        def httpUrl = WebFacadeImpl.getWebappRootUrl('webroot',null,false,false,ec)
    </script>
</actions>
```

This is the log:

```
21:47:18.996  WARN oquiWorker-2      o.moqui.i.c.TransactionFacadeImpl Transaction set rollback only. The rollback was originally caused by: Error rendering screen [component://HS-data/screen/Notification/PayablesDue.xml]
```

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.moqui.impl.context.WebFacadeImpl.makeWebappHost(WebFacadeImpl.groovy:477) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.context.WebFacadeImpl.makeWebappRootUrl(WebFacadeImpl.groovy:520) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.context.WebFacadeImpl.getWebappRootUrl(WebFacadeImpl.groovy:467) ~[moqui-framework-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.moqui.impl.context.WebFacadeImpl$getWebappRootUrl.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) ~[groovy-2.4.7.jar:2.4.7]
    at PayablesDue_xml_screen_actions.run(PayablesDue_xml_screen_actions:11) ~[script:?]

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the WebFacade.getWebappRootUrl() method. Use a call that is something like this in your template to get the base URL:

```
ec.web.getWebappRootUrl(true, null)
```

When there is no WebFacade in place, such as when running in an async service, you'll have to drop a level lower and there is a static method in WebFacadeImpl for this (it's not so convenient when you don't have the standard interfaces to go through), here is the method signature:

```
String getWebappRootUrl(String webappName, String servletContextPath, boolean requireFullUrl, Boolean useEncryption, ExecutionContextImpl eci)
```

The standard webappName is 'webroot' and unless you're doing something fancy in your Moqui Conf XML file this can be a static String. The servletContextPath can be null or an empty String if your Moqui webapp is mounted on the root (commonly the case; without a request where we can get to the ServletContext to see where it is mounted this can't be determined automatically).

Comment: I added a comment into the original message.

Comment: I see the NPE in there and the cause of it, changed some code (commit #3cb17b5) so it will better handle null webFacade and request. Note that for correct URLs without a request available you can't use virtual hosting, the http-host, https-host, etc on the webapp element in Moqui Conf XML must be set.